# in jenkins, how do i paramerize the build name so that it includes the commiter name

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

I want to name the builds in jenkins to include the commiter's name, I wonder if there is an environment variable that contains the commiters name

I installed Build User Vars Plugin, but when the scm triggers it, build user is scmTrigger. how do i get the actual commiter's name?

Answer (score 0):

Git Plugin can do this for you, but the question is do you using git, if you do you can set next env variables:

GIT_COMMIT - SHA of the current

GIT_BRANCH - Name of the branch currently being used, e.g. "master" or "origin/foo"

GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT - SHA of the previous built commit from the same branch (the current

SHA on first build in branch)

GIT_URL - Repository remote URL

GIT_URL_N - Repository remote URLs when there are more than 1 remotes, e.g. GIT_URL_1,

GIT_URL_2

GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL - Committer/Author Email

GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL - Committer/Author Email

Also question is why this is needed on this level, it's not good point to see when somebody commit something wrong, this is waste of time, that should be done before jenkins job execution!

Comment: I need something such as GIT_COMMITER_NAME, but apparently i did echo $GIT_COMMITER_NAME (or email) it gave me blank, it is not available through jenkins. the reason why i need this is so taht ppl can see themselves in queue, or spot themselves on buildhistory page